# How to implode input's ids using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are few inputs

```
<input id=1>
<input id=12>
<input id=14>
<input id=16>
<input id=28>
```

How to implode ids to a string '1,12,14,16,28'?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) convert the input objects to an array of ids then use Array.join() to convert them to a string

```
var ids = $('input').map(function(){
    return this.id
}).get().join()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4ZXd6/)